# Can I use ResultSetMapping->addEntityResult() with an Entity that doesn't have a database table?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Getting this error:

```
Class "Bundle\LeagueStanding" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.
```

When I use this:

```
$sql = '......';

$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
$rsm->addEntityResult('Bundle:LeagueStanding', 's');
$rsm->addFieldResult('s', 'played', 'played');
//........etc
$query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);

return $query->getResult();
```

LeagueStanding doesn't have a database table and that's the way I'd like to keep it to enforce normalization (don't store calculated values). Is it possible to still use ResultSetMapping with an Entity that doesn't have a database table? A DTO so to speak?

```
namespace Bundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Bundle\Entity\League;
use Bundle\Entity\Team;
use Bundle\Entity\Season;

class LeagueStanding
{
    private $position = 0;

    private $played = 0;

    private $homePlayed = 0;

    private $awayPlayed = 0;

    private $won = 0;

    private $homeWon = 0;

    private $awayWon = 0;

    private $lost = 0;

    .................

    ......
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed it looks like ResultSetMapping can only be used with existing Entities.
Since Doctrine 2.4 it is possible to use any PHP class / POPO using the [“NEW” Operator Syntax](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#quot-new-quot-operator-syntax):

```
<?php
class CustomerDTO
{
    public function __construct($name, $email, $city, $value = null)
    {
        // Bind values to the object properties.
    }
}

<?php
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT NEW CustomerDTO(c.name, e.email, a.city) FROM Customer c JOIN c.email e JOIN c.address a');
$users = $query->getResult(); // array of CustomerDTO
```

> You can specify any PHP class, it only requires that the constructor of this class matches the NEW statement.

Feel free to [join our discussion on these strategies](https://github.com/webdevilopers/php-ddd/issues/16) with PHP and Domain-Driven Design.

Comment: Indeed, at the time I asked this question I don't think this feature was available. I will mark this as the answer.